# Mysql create columns from certain rows of tables

Tags: mysql, sql, pivot

I have these three tables

Table #1: Ships IDs

```
Ship ID                         Ship Code
1                               ALBE
2                               AMBS
3                               AMBR
```

Table #2 : Equipment Data

```
Ship ID               Equipment_ID           
1                       1001
1                       1002
1                       1003
2                       1004
2                       1005
2                       1006
3                       1007
3                       1008
3                       1009
```

Table #3 : Counters

```
Equipment_ID       Hours          Date_Updated
1001                2                2018-01-01
1001                4                2018-05-01
1002                3                2018-01-01
1002                5                2018-05-01
1003                5                2018-01-01
1003                10               2018-05-01
1004                1                2018-01-01
1004                6                2018-05-01
1005                3                2018-03-01
1006                6                2018-03-01
1007                5                2018-01-01
1007                12               2018-05-01
1008                15               2018-01-01
1008                19               2018-05-01
1009                4                2018-01-01
1009                12               2018-06-01
```

I want the below result:

Per each Ship Code the last counter hours and equipment_id categorized as AE1,AE2,AE3 where AE1 are 1001,1004,1007 AE2 are 1002,1005,1008 and AE3 are 1003,1006,1009

```
Ship Code       AE1         AE2         AE3
ALBE            4           5           10
AMBS            6           6           12
AMBR            12          19          12
```

How can I create this **dynamic** pivot table?

Comment: We are not going to write the code for you. Make an attempt and we will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.ship_code,
       sum(case when e.equipment_id in (1001, 1004, 1007) then hours else 0 end) as ae1,
       sum(case when e.equipment_id in (1001, 1004, 1007) then hours else 0 end) as ae2,
       sum(case when e.equipment_id in (1003,1 006, 1009) then hours else 0 end) as ae3
from ships s left join
     equipment e
     on e.ship_id = s.ship_id left join
     counters c
     on c.equipment_id = e.equipment_id
group by s.ship_code;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could approach the pivot table like so:

```
 Ship Code       Equipment ID           Hour Type       
 ALBE            4                      AE1
 AMBS            6                      AE1
 AMBR            12                     AE2
 AMBR            12                     AE3
```

That way you could query it more easily